# Is there a replacement for ERR_load_SSL_strings() since it is deprecated?

Tags: openssl, deprecated

Compiling one of my libraries on Ubuntu 22.04, I get a deprecated error on the `ERR_load_SSL_strings()` call. There is no comment other than the date when it was deprecated. Searching with Google doesn't return anything useful.

Is there a replacement to that function? or can we do without it now?

Comment: Since it *is* deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a replacement to that function? or can we do without it now?

There is no replacement. You don't need to call it anymore. Error strings are loaded automatically since OpenSSL 1.1.0.